# How to run grails-vue profile within a docker container?

Tags: docker, grails, webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

I have created a docker image for grails on dockerhub:

> https://hub.docker.com/r/dhobdensa/docker-alpine-grails/

It is based on the official openjdk:alpine image

---

First I run the container:

```
docker container run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 -p 3000:3000 dhobdensa/docker-alpine-grails
```

Then I create a new grails app with the vue profile

```
grails create-app --inplace --profile vue
```

And then I run the app:

```
./gradlew bootRun -parallel
```

Which starts a grails REST API server, and a vue client app using vue-cli and webpack

---

The server says your app is running on localhost:8080. This can be accessed and returns the expected result.

The client says your app is running on localhost:3000. But when attempting to access this, the browser just shows the default ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE page.

I have tried different browsers and clearing caches.

Any ideas why accessing port 3000 is not working, but 8080 is?

**Additional info**

It seems that gradle is essentially running this command:

```
webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js
```

And this is the file:

https://gist.github.com/dhobdensa/4e22a188cc2b26cf5b0dd4028755d39b

Perhaps this is linked to webpack dev server?

Comment: What if you try to access to the app if you are into the container. I mean to say, can you do a curl localhost:3030 running from the container

Comment: Ok good suggestion, So I just tried this and it does return html when I curl from inside the container

Comment: I am starting to suspect that webpack dev server is the culprit, have updated the question with more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found my answer.

I suspected that webpack dev server was the place to be looking.

Then I found this issue on github:

**Cant run webpack-dev-server inside of a docker container?**

https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/547

Long story short, I had to add --host 0.0.0.0 to the "dev" task in package.json

```
"dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js --host 0.0.0.0"
```